# Python: Assign single value to each value in array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, concatenation

I am new to python. The code below creates a range of numerical values based on inputs from a csv data set, for each key in **newprobValues**. I would like to be able to identify which values were created via each **arange()** function, by assigning each new numerical values another value (i.e. 0, 1, 2)

Right now, all of the new numerical values are aggregated into one list, and I'm pulling numbers randomly out of that list and deleting them after use (in a psychology PsychoPy task). Data from the task is output into another csv file, and i would like to have a column of 0s, 1s, and 2s next to the column of new numerical values so that I can parse them for analysis.

for example: 
    each value to come out of **newprobValues1 = np.arange(low1_p, high1_p, step = SV)** should have a second value of 1 associated it, so that I can output those values to a separate column in a csv file.

code:

```
newprobValues = {.17:[],
         .28:[],
         .54:[],
         .84:[],
         .96:[],
         .99:[],}

for npv in newprobValues: 
    mu = probs.ix[(probs['DDPD']==npv),['Value']]
    SV = hyperlaw(((1-npv)/npv), k_prob) #yields subjective value of one dollar at given delay
    mu = float(mu['Value'])
    generating_values_prob[npv] = {'mu':mu, 'SV':SV}
    if mu >= 25.50:
        #set desired ran
        low1_p, high1_p = float(mu-(4*SV)), float(mu-.01) # -.01 is hack to prevent arange() from      rounding uneven ceil() up to a fifth iteration
        low2_p, high2_p = float(mu+SV), float(mu+(5*SV)-.01) 
        low3_p, high3_p = 20.5, 80
        newprobValues1 = np.arange(low1_p, high1_p, step = SV) #generate hard values below indiff point
        newprobValues2 = np.arange(low2_p, high2_p, step = SV) #generate hard values above indiff point
        newprobValues3 = np.arange(low3_p, high3_p, step = 6.612)**
        newprobValues[npv] = np.concatenate([newprobValues1, newprobValues2, newprobValues3])
        newprobValues[npv] = np.insert(newprobValues[npv], 0, mu)
        newprobValues[npv] = newprobValues[npv].tolist()
```

I have tried the code:

```
    newprobValues1 = {'value': np.arange(low1_p, high1_p, step = SV), 'type': 0}
```

but I get a dictionary with 0 in it, when I really need 0 to be assigned to each number -- so that when I concatenate shuffle the arrays I can still identify the `arange()` function that generated each value

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what exactly you would like to do. It may help if you create a very simple dummy data frame `probs` for us and tell us, what output you expect for this data frame.

Comment: Can you change the data structure of ```newprobValues[npv]```? You can separate the *values* within the data structure if you use ```np.vstack``` instead of ```np.concatenate```.  Then it should be  easy to extract them later.  Is ```mu``` a scaler?

Comment: @wwii mu is a scalar. using np.vstack, do you think it would be possible to identify which array a number is in? That is, when I pull and delete a number from one of the a arrays in the stack, how would I also be able to get info on which array in the stack it was pulled from? e.g. array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), and I pull out 6, is it possible to also identify that 6 came from the second array?

Comment: @cel sorry for any confusion. in general, i would like to create new scalars using the arange() function, save those new numbers to a dictionary, later pull out and delete those numbers from the dictionary (for use in an experimental task) -- importantly, while also being able to identify which arange() function generated the number.

Comment: @cel part of the issue is that I'm not sure what the best approach is. Wwii's vstack tip, sounds promising, but I also wonder if it would work to create a list of tuples (i, j), where i of the tuple is the scalar returned by the arange() function, and the j identifies the arange() function in which scalar was generated. 

for example: (4, 0), the 4 was generated by the arange() function, and the 0 means the 4 was generated in the arange() function. 

please let me know if example code would be more helpful. thank you for taking the time to look this over!

Comment: As with gboffi's answer, which is probably best suited for your needs, You know which *dataset* an element/item comes from beforehand because of the way you have to index the *container* to get that number. - Looking closer at your code, it seems that the three *values* can be of different lengths so ```np.vstack``` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the last thing you do with the newly computed `ndarray` is
using its `tolist()` method.

```
# last line of your code
newprobValues[npv] = newprobValues[npv].tolist()
```

If what you want is a list, you needn't go through the hoops of
`numpy`... a more natural approach would be

```
newprobValues[npv].append(mu)
newprobValues[npv].append(newprobValues1)
newprobValues[npv].append(newprobValues2)
newprobValues[npv].append(newprobValues3)
```

later, when you want to use the sequence number `i` you can do

```
result  = use(newprobValues[npv][i])
```

or, using list unpacking

```
for npv in newprobValues:
    mu, seq1, seq2, seq3 = newprobValues[npv]
    ...
```

Comment: Or ```.append(newprobValuesX.tolist())``` if that is the desired container.

Comment: @wwii Thank you for the clarification, I hope that the OP can decide which approach to choose

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but the built-in `enumerate()` function will generate pairs of values,  the first member of each pair being an index. So, for example, `enumerate([12, 35, 17)` will produce the sequence `(0, 12), (1, 35), (2, 17)`.

Would it work for you to change to `for` loop to read

```
for index, npv in enumerate(newprobValues):
    ...

    newprobValues1 = {'value': np.arange(low1_p, high1_p, step = SV), 'type': index}
```

I wonder?

Comment: I think she wants to enumerate ```newprobValues1```, ```newprobValues2```, and ```newprobValues3```.  Which could be done  by making a list of ```(lowx_p, highx_p)``` tuples and iterating over it.